# Find all TEXAS and change into Tx

Tags: r, string

If I have a list similar to:

| First |
| --- |
| FirstPlace TEXAS |
| SecondPlace Texas |
| ThirdPlace, Tx |

How can I make them all look like the following:

| First |
| --- |
| FirstPlace, Tx |
| SecondPlace, Tx |
| ThirdPlace, Tx |

I could probably do this within excel's Find and Replace but I'd like to have a script I can run a series of actions in.

Answer (score 1):

Try `regex` with `sub`, e.g.,

```
> s <- c("FirstPlace TEXAS", "SecondPlace Texas", "ThirdPlace, Tx")

> sub("\\stexas", ", Tx", s, ignore.case = TRUE)
[1] "FirstPlace, Tx"  "SecondPlace, Tx" "ThirdPlace, Tx"
```

Comment: @Would this work if there is lettering AFTER the word Texas, too?

Comment: @Antonio yes, it would work